# How can I add a package to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, package, qt4.6

I downloaded a package called QtIOCompressor, I need to use the functionality like zipping a directory gzipping a directory etc etc in a application I am coding. But I dont know how to add this package into Qt or how to configure this package by which i can use it with my application which i may code in future!

InfO: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtiocompressor/qtiocompressor.html
download: http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtiocompressor/

Comment: Which platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: I am using windows 7 for this. But would like to know how its done on both ubuntu and windows. windows will be my first priority! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. step: read the INSTALL.TXT that comes with the package and follow the instructions. Basically that is just: qmake and nmake
2. step: look at the .pro files in the example directory for usage in your program. (you just have to include src/qtiocompressor.pri

Comment: but I have done as per they said in install.txt. But after that what should i do, and i hv installed this package from my desktop, can i delete that files, or should i keep it in somewhere? i mean whether thes files are needed for including it in my application code!

Comment: @oDx: how much experience do you have with software development in general, and C++ on Windows in particular? Your title suggests you've got a Qt problem, but the question itself and your comments suggest that you're not familiar with concepts like compiling, linking, and libraries.

Comment: I am pretty new in this field. especially in adding packages, libraries etc.